# Transform an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) in F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, abstract-syntax-tree, discriminated-union

I am trying to design an AST for a decision logic table.  One of the things I would like to be able to do with the discriminated union that represents my AST is transform parts of it for different reasons.  For clarity I will give you an example

**Decision Logic Table**

> @ VAR = 10 ;Y;

The above can be read as there is one rule and the condition VAR = 10 enters this rule with a Y entry.

**Abstract Syntax Tree Definition (simplified for this example)**

```
 type expression = 
     | Value of double
     | Variable of string 
     | Equality of expression * expression

type entry =
    | Entry of string

type entries =
    | Entries of entry list

type conditional =
    | ConditionEntries of expression * entries

type condition
    | Condition of expression * string

type rule = 
    | Rule of condition list
```

**Rendered (before transform)**

```
ConditionEntries(
    Equality(
        Variable("VAR"), 
        Value(10.0)), 
    Entries(["Y"]))
```

**Rendered (after transform)**

```
Rule(
    Condition(
        Equality(
            Variable("VAR"),
            Value(10.0)
        ),
        Entry("Y")
    )
)
```

Now what I would like to do is transform the above tree to expand the rules that are represented in the entries.  My thinking was I could use a recursive function and pattern-matching to do this but I am having a little trouble wrapping my head around it right now.

I guess in essence what I am trying to do is whenever I see a ConditionEntries node, I want to emit a new Rule for every string in the Entries list where the Condition is combined with the Entry.  Does that make any sense?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

p.s. I haven't quite tried to compile the above example, so please forgive any grammatical errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, based on your AST, which is awfully broken up, here is a `tranform` function which produces the output from input you desire (though it's not recursive, just uses `List.map` with some pattern matching. `expression` is your only recursive type but it doesn't look like you want to process it recursively?):

```
let ex1 =
    ConditionEntries(
        Equality(
            Variable("VAR"), 
            Value(10.0)), 
        Entries([Entry("Y")]))

let ex2 =
    ConditionEntries(
        Equality(
            Variable("VAR"), 
            Value(10.0)), 
        Entries([Entry("X");Entry("Y");Entry("Z")]))

let transform ces =
    match ces with
    | ConditionEntries(x, Entries(entries)) ->
        entries
        |> List.map (function Entry(entry) -> Condition(x, entry))


//FSI output:
> transform ex1;;
val it : condition list =
  [Condition (Equality (Variable "VAR",Value 10.0),"Y")]
> transform ex2;;
val it : condition list =
  [Condition (Equality (Variable "VAR",Value 10.0),"X");
   Condition (Equality (Variable "VAR",Value 10.0),"Y");
   Condition (Equality (Variable "VAR",Value 10.0),"Z")]
```

Comment: Sorry about the broken up AST, I thought I would include only the relevant portions for brevity.  Thanks for the answer, I will give this a try later.  One more question though:  would the transform function change much if ConditionEntries and Condition were under another node? (i.e. I would only want to change "part" of the tree as opposed to the entirety)

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, no worries, the broken up AST is not offensive to me, I was just expressing concern that the way you've modeled your language might be too complex (too much semantics built into your AST?).

Comment: Regarding your follow up question, I'm not sure without seeing the big picture, but generally if you only want to transform part of a tree, you can have a final catch-all match which just returns the branch of the tree unchanged, something like `... | branch -> branch`